# Show contractibility implies single set proof

Tags: solution-verification, homotopy-theory

Problem. Suppose $Y$ is a contractible space. Let $X$ be any space. Then $[X,Y]$, the set of homotopy classes, has only one element.

Proof:

Suppose $Y$ is contractible. So $Y$ is path connected. Let $X$ be any space. Let $[f],[g]\in [X,Y]$. It suffices to show that there exists a homotopy between $f$ and $g$. Since $Y$ is path connected, for each $x\in X$, there exists a continuous map $f_x:I\rightarrow Y$ such that $f_x(0)=f(x)$ and $f_x(1)=g(x)$. Define

$F:X\times I\rightarrow Y$ by $F(x,t)=f_x(t)$.

This map is the desired homotopy.

Is the proof correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not quite correct, as you have not ensured that $F$ be continuous. The idea is correct, but as stated, you are picking maps $f_x$ for each $x$, and we need these to also depend continuously on $x$.

To be contractible means that the identity map is homotopic to a constant map. So for some fixed point $y_0\in Y$, we have a continuous homotopy $G\colon Y\times I\to Y$ where $g_0(y)=G(y,0)=y$ and $g_1(y)=y_0$ for all $y$.

Now given $f\colon X\to Y$, we can define $F\colon X\times I\to Y\times I$ as $f'(x,t)=(f(x),t)$. The composition $G\circ F$ is now a map $X\times I\to Y$ which is guaranteed to be continuous. At time $0$ this composition is $(x,0)\mapsto (f(x),0)\mapsto f(x)$, and at time $1$ it is the constant map.

This shows that every map $f\colon X\to Y$ is homotopic to the *same* constant map, so $[X,Y]$ has one point.

Comment: Right, okay. That makes much more sense. Thanks!

Comment: Under what conditions will I be able to guarantee that my map, $F$, varies continuously in its first argument?

Comment: Well that can be difficult. I guess my best advice is to try to avoid "pointwise" arguments, if that makes sense. Usually questions of this flavor can be answered by using the right combination of homotopies that you already know to exist. The non-interventionist approach, if you will